# Is $\nabla\cdot\hat{\frac{r}{r^3}}=-\frac{1}{r^4}+\frac{1}{r}4\pi\delta\vec{r}$ correct?

Tags: vector-analysis, dirac-delta, divergence-operator

Using $\hat{\frac{r}{r^2}}=4\pi\delta(\vec{r})$, I solved  $\nabla\hat{\frac{r}{r^3}}$ in following steps.

$\nabla\cdot\hat{\frac{r}{r^3}}\\
=\nabla\cdot\frac{1}{r}\hat{\frac{r}{r^2}}\\
=\hat{\frac{r}{r^2}}\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}\nabla\hat{\frac{r}{r^2}}\\
=-\frac{1}{r^4}+\frac{1}{r}4\pi\delta(\vec{r})$

However, if I directly use divergence formula of spherical coordinate on $\nabla\cdot\hat{\frac{r}{r^3}},   \nabla\cdot\hat{\frac{r}{r^3}}$ is just $-\frac{1}{r^4}$ .

Which one is correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

The divergence formula in spherical coordinates only is valid for $r\ne 0$, where your function is differentiable in the usual sense. [Dirac $\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is  a derivative in the [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) sense.